# Print the address that stores the pointer points to an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, implicit-conversion

This question may seems quite duplicated; however, I indeed have had a serious survey on this site and still cannot quite understand.

```c
    char str[] = "test";
    printf("%p\n", str);
    printf("%p\n", &str);
```

I know `str` itself is a pointer which points to the starting location that stores "t". Therefore I expect that `printf("%p\n", str);` shows this address (say `000000FFE94FFC34`). Next, I wish to know in my OS, at what memory location that stores the exact information `000000FFE94FFC34`. (i.e. the address of `str` itself.)

However, the output of the third line is the same as the previous one. It seems quite a weird behavior. And how can I figure out the address of `str` itself? I guess this can be achieved by using another new pointer that points to the pointer I want, i.e. `char **super_pointer = str;` but I think it is an unnecessarily complicated way.

Comment: No, your `str` designates *an array*, not a pointer.  These are not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know str itself is a pointer which points to the starting location
> that stores "t".

As you wrote "str itself" is not a pointer it is an array. But used in expressions array designators with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In this call

```
printf("%p\n", str);
```

the array designator `str` used as an argument expression is converted to a pointer to its first element. In fact this call is equivalent to

```
printf("%p\n", &str[0]);
```

That is this call outputs the starting address of the extent of memory occupied by the array.

This call

```
printf("%p\n", &str);
```

that is better to write as and the previous call like

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )&str);
```

also outputs the starting address of the extent of the memory occupied by the array.

What is the difference?

The expression `str`  used in the call of `printf` has the type `char *` while the expression `&str`  has the type `char ( * )[5]`.

The both expressions is interpreted by the call as expressions of the type `void *`.

To make this more clear consider a two dimensional array

```
char str[2][6] = { "test1", "test2" };
```

The addresses of the array as whole and of its first "row" and of its first character of the first "row" are coincide.

That is the expression `&sgtr` that has the type `char ( * )[2][6]` and the expression `&str[0]` that has the type `char ( * )[6]` and the expression `&str[0][0]` that has the type `char *` yield the same value: hhe starting address of the extent of memory occupied by the array..

Answer (score 3):

Lets draw it out with the pointers added, to hopefully make it simpler to understand:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| str[0] | str[1] | str[2] | str[3] | str[4] |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
^
|
&str[0]
|
&str
```

As you can see the pointer to the first element (`&str[0]` which is what plain `str` decays to) points to the same location as the array itself (`&str`).

***But*** (and it's an important but): The type are very different!

The type of `&str[0]` is `char *`.

The type of `&str` is `char (*)[5]`.

---

On another note you say that

> ... `str` itself is a pointer...

This is *wrong*. `str` itself is the array, which can *decay* to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Can I print the memory location where the OS stores the "address" of `&str[0]` or `&str`?

Comment: @Eric The expression `&str` results in an *rvalue* which doesn't have to be stored anywhere. `str` and `str[0]` are stored in memory, the results of expressions isn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude such a common dupe

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I wonder what will happen if I write `char *ptr=&str`. Actually I should use `char (*ptr)[5]=&str`. But how if I use a more little type `char` to interpret a bigger size `sizeof(char)*5`? Will `ptr++` make any sense?

Comment: @Eric `char *ptr=&str` is incorrect, just don't do it.

Comment: I see. Can I use type casting (perhaps something like `char *str=(...)&str`)? Is that legal? (Just wonder for a solid understanding!)
Because I used to cast a `uint64_t` array to `uint8_t` before calling a function with `uint8_t` argument (can work, until now...). I hope I did it properly.

Comment: @Eric This is turning too much into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Please post a new question where you detail the actual and underlying problem you try to solve, and tell us why you think using the wrong type of pointer would solve that problem.